# Best way to make Python class for multiple components?, example Chromatograpy

Tags: python, class

I want to create a Python Class for a specific Hydrocarbon Chromatography, where the user only provide the molar composition of certain components which I already have their physical properties required to make some estimations:

```
                  formula       mw      ppc     tpc
name                                               
methane               CH4  16.0430   666.40 -116.67
ethane               C2H6  30.0700   706.50   89.92
propane              C3H8  44.0970   616.00  206.06
isobutane           C4H10  58.1230   527.90  274.46
n-butane            C4H10  58.1230   550.60  305.62
...                   ...      ...      ...     ...
nitrogen               N2  28.0134   493.10 -232.51
chlorine              CL2  70.9060  1157.00  290.75
water                 H2O  18.0153  3198.80  705.16
helium                 HE   4.0026    32.99 -450.31
hydrogen-chloride     HCL  36.4610  1205.00  127.77

[64 rows x 4 columns]
```

I though initially to make a Component class like this:

```
class component():
    def __init__(self,name, symbol, mw, ppc, tpc):
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.mw = mw #Molecular Weight
        self.ppc = ppc #Pressure Pseudo-critical
        self.tpc = tpc #Temperature Pseudo-critical
```

However I don't know how to proceed in order to have a Class who groups the components that user define.

A user might have a DataFrame like this.

```
        name     y
0    methane  0.75
1     ethane  0.10
2    propane  0.08
3  isobutane  0.07
```

I'd like the user to be able to make some calculations based on the composition provided and the properties table.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. But how is your user-defined DataFrame {name, y} related to the original data?

Comment: The user-defined dataframe provides the composition (y) of each component. I could estimate for example the apparent molecular weight by summing the product of 'y' and 'mw' for each component. And much more calculations can be made.

Comment: Then, I guess what you need is to merge the 2 dataframes. You could refer to answer by Busykoala, to see one possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand your goal correctly.

If it's about merging the two data frames you can do something like:

```
df_one.merge(df_two, on=['name'], how='outer')
```

If it is about initiating an object by e.g. the name only you could pass that into `def __init__(self, name):` and then collect the rest from the existing data frames (e.g. `some_row = df_one.loc[df_one['name'] == 'methane']`).